# Are there Array as a Table easy to use?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a fixed data which will be used in a UITableView later and the user will not update/add on  this data.

This data looks like a table with 4 column:

Name (String) | Tel (INT) | Logo (URL) | PDF File (URL)

The UITableView will be fill with this data and if the user select a row he will navigate to another pages which show the PDF file.

The question is should I use the core data or Array, if the answer is Array how can I have column in the Array?

Thanx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use an array with a NSDictionary inside. Both structures might be mutable and you can use the dictionary to simulate what you call columns.
Example:

```
[myMutDict setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[myMutDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:n] forKey:@"number"];

[myMutArray addObject:myMutDict];
```

I'd not go for coredata

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath you'll select your data like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [myMutArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
int tel = [[dict objectForKey:@"number"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

For this it is better to use NSMutable Array.
For this data to save in NSArray Initially you need to save every row in a NSMutableDictionary like

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:4];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"Name"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"Tel"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"Logo"];
[dictionary setObject:value forKey:@"PDF File"];
```

so add this dictionary to a NSMutableArray like this

```
[array addObject:dictionary];
```

You can easily retrive the data from array